# Is MariaDB's Aria storage engine suitable for WordPress?

Tags: database, mysql, innodb

MySQL sites are steadily migrating away from the older [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) storage engine to [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-introduction.html). That's because InnoDB [has better recovery and row-by-row transaction locking support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines).

At the same time, many hosting providers and people who run their own servers are adopting the MySQL database fork called [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/). (It's compatible. A couple of providers I use switched to MariaDB without telling anybody, and nobody noticed.)

MariaDB offers the [Aria](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aria-storage-engine/) storage engine in addition to [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-introduction.html) and [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html). Aria's a successor to InnoDB. It's being actively developed by the original MySQL team led by Monty Widenius. (This Aria has no relationship to [HTML's aria accessibility stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA).)

My question: **Is there any advantage to using Aria for WordPress?** Do the old statements about MyISAM being faster than InnoDB for read-mostly sites (sites with heavy readership) apply to Aria?